# Parallax effect with page builder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, parallax

I have a `PageView.builder` and each page has an image in the background. I want to add a parallax effect when changing pages, and I achieved it by giving an `Offset` in the image `Alignment` property. The problem is that when the page is about to end it starts to show the background, I suppose it's because due to the given `Offset` the image ended, so it starts to show the background. What can I do to solve this?

### This is my `PageView.builder`

```
body: PageView.builder(
                controller: _controller,
                itemCount: _philosophers.length,
                onPageChanged: _onPageChange,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final philosopher = _philosophers[index];
                  return Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage(philosopher.image),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        alignment: Alignment((dx - index) * 1.8, 0),
                      ),
                    ),
```

### This is the `PageController`

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = PageController();
    _controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        dx = _controller.page ?? 0.0;
      });
    });
  }
```

### Current result

[Parallax effect](https://i.imgur.com/wQ9eP1Q.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clamp` for horizontal alignment to fix this issue, here is the modified code:

```dart
body: PageView.builder(
  controller: _controller,
  itemCount: _philosophers.length,
  onPageChanged: _onPageChange,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    final philosopher = _philosophers[index];
    final alignmentX = ((dx - index) * 1.8).clamp(-1.0, 1.0);

    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage(philosopher.image),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          alignment: Alignment(alignmentX, 0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
),
```